# How to pause the completion of a for loop until the AudioIsCompletedCondition is met

Tags: android, kotlin, multimedia

I have a PlayAll function which is supposed to

1. cycle through a list of phrases (in a recyclerView),
2. highlight the selected ViewHolder a certain colour
3. play the audio of that phrase
4. change the colour back to normal, and move onto the next phrase repeating all previous steps.

I've tried 2 ways:

```
for (i in termList.indices){
        val viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder = recyclerView!!.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)
        val mp = MediaPlayer.create (activity, termList[i].audio!!)
        viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"))
        mp.setOnCompletionListener {
            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
        }
        mp.start ()
    }
```

This way plays them all at once, changes the colour of all cells to #D3... and only iterates through setting the colour back to #FFFFFF once complete.

```
fun playAllAudio(i: Int){

    while (i <= termList.size){
        val viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder = recyclerView!!.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)
        val mp = MediaPlayer.create (activity, termList[i].audio!!)
        viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"))
        mp.setOnCompletionListener {
            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
            playAllAudio(i+1)
        }
        mp.start ()
    }
```

This way creates a feedback loop of playing all the audios until the app crashes.

The first way is less crazy and seems closer to what the solution actually is, but I'm struggling to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `while` to an `if` in the second example, and change `<=` to `<`:

```
fun playAllAudio(i: Int){

    if (i < termList.size){
        val viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder = recyclerView!!.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)
        val mp = MediaPlayer.create (activity, termList[i].audio!!)
        viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"))
        mp.setOnCompletionListener {
            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
            playAllAudio(i+1)
        }
        mp.start ()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can I only accept an answer in 6 minutes? It took me 3 seconds to see that your answer was completely correct. Thanks!

Comment: @Glenncito it's so that others have time to post their own answers, which might be better than the first one posted. It's still possible that someone will have a better solution.